# react native - navigate back and forth between screens without losing screen data

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want the user to fill a form step by step. So right now i have 3 screens with data stored in each screen (via useState) and when user is done with this screen i navigate to the next screen and pass the data along through screen params.
This works fine except when user goes back and forth between the screens, then data from the last step gets lost, because screen gets killed and user would have to reenter it.
So i'm wondering what would be the best way to solve this issue?

---

react native 0.64
react navigation 5

Answer (score 0):

My favourite way to deal with this sort of multi-page data storing is to use React Context. This way you can add and read which data you've gathered across any component (or in this case screen) that you have wrapped in the provider.

Here's a good resource: https://betterprogramming.pub/react-hooks-and-forms-dedb8072763a